# Change Symbology of layers from within ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, symbology

In an active ArcMap session - I want to change the symbology of a layer which is repeated multiple times in the mxd. Can I do this?

The basic code I have for getting the layers is below. This is running within ArcMap (not as a .py script)

```
myMXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
lstDataFrames=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(myMXD)
lstLayers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myMXD)

hazardLayer=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myMXD,'*Haz*')

allFrames=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(myMXD)

for dataFrame in allFrames:
    myMXD.activeView=dataFrame
    for mapLayer in hazardLayer:
        mapLayer.visible=False
```

This just changes the visibility to off...can I change the color for example to some RGB value?

Comment: GeogeC,what the sign Haz with the 2 Asterisk mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create a default layer file to use as a template then:

```
myMXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
lstDataFrames=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(myMXD)
lstLayers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myMXD)

hazardLayer=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myMXD,'*Haz*')

allFrames=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(myMXD)

for dataFrame in allFrames:
     myMXD.activeView=dataFrame
     for mapLayer in hazardLayer:
         arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(mapLayer, r"C:\TemplateLayers\HazardTemplate.lyr")
```

Comment: Thanks...that's great. Is this also possible with the symbology of .shp files and not only .lyr files?

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [Apply Symbology From Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm) tool.

> This tool applies the symbology from a layer to the Input Layer. It
>   can be applied to feature, raster, network analysis, TIN, and
>   geostatistical layer files or layers in the ArcMap table of contents.
>   This tool is primarily for use in scripts or ModelBuilder.

Comment: Updated answer with tool description.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to similar question [Changing color of symbol in UniqueValuesSymbology object using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89271/changing-color-of-symbol-in-uniquevaluessymbology-object-using-arcpy/440459#440459) :

> Current answer for ArcMAP 10.8 (may be some previous versions too) is "yes, it's possible". You can use a Layer method `.updateLayerFromJSON`
>
> Core part of solution is to create JSON description of layer symbology.
>
> Code sample:
>
> ```
> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
> lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "name*")[0]
> lyr.updateLayerFromJSON(json_dictionary)
> ```
>
> There is a valid example for polygon layer with single symbol symbology.
>
> ```
> {"name": "pointLayer",
> "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
> "drawingInfo": {
>        "renderer":{
>        "type": "simple",
>        "symbol": {
>        "type": "esriSFS",
>        "style": "esriSFSSolid",
>        "color": [           76,           115,           0,           255          >],
>        "outline": {
>        "color": [            255,            0,            0,            255           >],
>        "width": 1          }}}}}
> ```
>
> Above code is a value of tag `layerDefinition` from this specification: >https://enterprise.arcgis.com/ru/server/10.8/create-web-apps/windows/exportwebmap->specification.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_FC212A2B579B425A9FE4358ACC89482A
>
> Details about specification can be found here: [https://developers.arcgis.com/web->map-specification/objects/renderer/](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-%3Emap-specification/objects/renderer/)