# Changing color of symbol in UniqueValuesSymbology object using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, layers, symbology

I have an template mxd I reference with several pre-defined layers. The only variable I need to modify is the color of certain symbols in the layer. I have tried to modify and dig around the Symbology Object but I cannot access the colors of each Unique Value Symbol.

This is how I am accessing the the Symbology of the individual layers. There doesn't seem to be and option to change the color a value.

- I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1

  ```
  mxd_file = r"some\path\file.mxd"
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_file)

  # getting data frame   
  df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

  # getting street layer
  street_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'Street', df)[0]

  if street_layer.symbologyType == 'UNIQUE_VALUES':
      # trying to access all possible properties of the symbology object
      street_symbology = street_layer.symbology
      desc = street_symbology.classDescription
      labels = street_symbology.classLabels
      values = street_symbology.classValues
      show_other_values = street_symbology.showOtherValues
      value_field = street_symbology.valueField
  del mxd, df

  layer_file = r"some\path\file.lyr"
  arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(path_layer, layer_file)
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the [comment by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89271/changing-color-of-symbol-in-uniquevaluessymbology-object-using-arcpy#comment124248_89271):

> The short answer is no. The only way I am aware using the standard
>   geo-processing tools is to use the Apply Symbology From Layer tool. It
>   may be possible to access the Symbology using python to drive
>   ArcObjects, you would have to do some research on that.

Answer (score 1):

Example of using [Apply Symbology From Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm) tool with Python. Start by defining symbology for the first layer in map and then use this to set symbology of all other layers:

```
import arcpy
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyrlist=[f.name for f in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)]
lyrlist=lyrlist[1:] #exclude the first layer
for lyr in lyrlist:
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr,"templateSymbologyLayer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Current answer for ArcMAP 10.8 (may be some previous versions too) is "yes, it's possible". You can use a Layer method `.updateLayerFromJSON`

Core part of solution is to create JSON description of layer symbology.

Code sample:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "name*")[0]
lyr.updateLayerFromJSON(json_dictionary)
```

There is a valid example for polygon layer with single symbol symbology.

```
{"name": "pointLayer",
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
"drawingInfo": {
        "renderer":{
        "type": "simple",
        "symbol": {
        "type": "esriSFS",
        "style": "esriSFSSolid",
        "color": [           76,           115,           0,           255          ],
        "outline": {
        "color": [            255,            0,            0,            255           ],
        "width": 1          }}}}}
```

Above code is a value of tag `layerDefinition` from this specification: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/ru/server/10.8/create-web-apps/windows/exportwebmap-specification.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_FC212A2B579B425A9FE4358ACC89482A

Details about specification can be found here: https://developers.arcgis.com/web-map-specification/objects/renderer/