# Using Python Script to change Pie Chart Symbology

Tags: arcpy, symbology, chart

I am trying to change the symbology for Pie chart in ArcGIS.

I have a feature class which is joined to a table and I will like to symbolized as a pie chart. I will be symbolizing it a lot thus I am looking for an automation ways to do this task. Map Layer does not work in this case.

I am very new to Python Scripting and I am wondering if there is there a way to add symbology using Python Script?

Answer (score 1):

With arcpy you can only modify the following types of symbology for vectors:

- [Graduated symbols](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/GraduatedSymbolsSymbology/00s30000005q000000/)
- [Graduated colors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/GraduatedColorsSymbology/00s30000005z000000/)
- [Unique values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/UniqueValuesSymbology/00s30000005s000000/).

You cannot actually change the type of symbology (e.g. from single symbol to graduated colors) but you can change some properties of the symbology type chosen.

Using arcpy this is anyway not possible with piecharts, as far as I know. You would need ArcObjects.

But, if you always symbolize the same feature class with a different defintion query, or if you use different feature classes with always the same schema, you could access the properties of the [layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) and modify its definitionQuery or dataSource properties, to automate your map production process.

Comment: +1 but [Apply Symbology From Layer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/9619) is probably worth mentioning here too.